# My spring mvc session was changed implicitly after called a service method?

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc

I'm using spring 3.2.5 via annotations and got some issue dealing with session.

My controller class is like this:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @Autowired
    private IElementService elementService;
    ...

    //in this method I set the "elementList" in session explicitly
    @RequestMapping("/elementSearch.do")
    public String elementSearch(
        @RequestParam("keyword") String keyword,
        HttpSession session){
        List<Element> elementList= elementService.searchElement(keyword);
        session.setAttribute("elementList", elementList);
        return "searchResult";
    }

    //here I got my problem
    @RequestMapping(value="/anotherMethod.do", produces="text/html; charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String anotherMethod(
        ...
        //I called my service method here like
        Element e = elementService.searchElement("something").get(0);
        ...
    }
```

And I have a ElementServiceImpl class like this:

```
@Service
public class ElementServiceImpl implements IElementService {
    @Autowired
    private IBaseDAO baseDao;

    @Override
    public List<Metadata> searchElement(String keyword) {
        List<Metadata> re = baseDao.searchElement(keyword);
        return re;
    }
}
```

And I have a BaseDAOImpl class implemented IBaseDAO and annonated with @Repository:

```
@Repository
public class BaseDAOImpl implements IBaseDAO {
    ...
}
```

Here is the problem, when I visit ".../anotherMethod.do", which will call the anotherMethod up there, my "elementList" in session was changed!
Then I looked into the anotherMethod() and found everytime

```
Element e = elementService.searchElement("something").get(0);
```

was called, my elementList was change to the new result returned by searchElement method(which returns a List).
But I didn't set session in that method, and I'm not using @SessionAttributes, so I don't understand how could my session attribute changed after calling a service method?

This problem is torturing me right now so any advise would be a great help, thanks!

---

update: I tried to print all my session attributes around that method call like this:

```
StringBuilder ss1 = new StringBuilder("-------------current session-------------\n");
session.setAttribute("test1", "test value 1");
log.info("sessionTest - key:test1  value:" + session.getAttribute("test"));
Enumeration<String> attrs1 = session.getAttributeNames();
while(attrs1.hasMoreElements()){
    String key = attrs1.nextElement();
    ss1.append(key).append(":").append(session.getAttribute(key)).append("\n");
}
log.info(ss1);
```

But I didn't see whether the "elementList" or the test value which I added just before print. And I do can get some value by

```
List<Element> elementList = (List<Element>) session.getAttribute("elementList");
```

and the elementList I get changed after calling service method, just like I posted before. Where my elementList stored? not in the session?

My goal is to show the elementList to the users in a table, and let them pick one of them,  then I get the row number of the table and take it as a index of the elemntList, so I'll know which elemnt object the user picked. Are there any better way to do this so I can get rid of that problem?
Thanks again.

Comment: change **if** (attrs1.hasMoreElements()) with **while** .. can you find your test value?

Comment: Yep, that's a stupid mistake, changed with while and I can see all the session attributes now. Thank you. And also I can see clearly the elementList was changed after the calling. I still don't know why.

Comment: have you tried to put some log to your searchElement method (dao or service) to check if they were actually called?

Comment: @EmanueleRighetto Yes, I got the correct search result from searchElement, and there isn't any code about httpsession in it. I just search the keyword in a local file.

Comment: this is very strange...

Comment: @EmanueleRighetto Yes...Anyway, thanks for your attention.